# Linux list loop issue

Tags: linux, list, unix, for-loop

I am using the find command to create a list of files. my issue is utilizing the output of it because of the syntax of the lies and folders. An example returned by the find command is in the variable $LIST
if i run

```
IFS=\n
echo "$LIST"
```

I will get

```
/C D/e f
/C D/t est
```

So if I use this in a for loop such as...

```
for file in $LIST
do
echo $file
echo "File printed"

done
```

I am getting

```
/C D/e f
/C D/t est 
File Printed
```

at the output as a single block by setting the IFS to \n
What I want and was expecting is

```
/C D/e f
File Printed
/C D/t est 
File Printed
```

Comment: What is your question? I don't see any difference in the two outputs. What's the problem?

Comment: Barmar I edited to be more clear. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To interpret the `\n` escape sequence as a newline, you need to use `$'...' syntax:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Or you can put a literal newline:

```
IFS='
'
```

Comment: IFS=$'\n'  Works perfectly. I guess I need to brush up on some of the syntax in this area. This is my first Linux class in 2 years and i guess its use it or lose it.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best way to act on the files you've found with the `find` command is not to use a `for` loop at all but to do it with the `-exec` switch:

```
find . -iname '*.java' -exec cp '{}' /tmp/backup/ ';'
```

This will look for all files matching `*.java` from the current directory and downwards, and then run

```
cp filename /tmp/backup/
```

on each one. You should look at the `man` page for `find`, but one thing to note in particular is that if you end with `';'` then the files will get processed one at a time, whereas if you end with `'+'` then lots will be processed together.

The other option is `xargs`, for which you really need to use `-print0` as a switch to `find` and then `-0` as a switch to `xargs` to avoid problems with spaces etc. in filenames:

```
find . -iname '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'static'
```

will look for `static` in all `.java` files.